# Longest Common Subsequence for trajectory matching in Python

Tags: python, trajectory

Is there any fast implementation of the Longest Common Subsequence algorithm for trajectory matching in Python? Ideally it would work with trajectories of different length in 2d spaces.

Comment: Do you have a quick link to save people from looking it up, specifically the reference you were examining

Comment: This is what I was working off of: http://www.cs.bu.edu/groups/dblab/pub_pdfs/icde02.pdf

Comment: The vertices of each matching sub sequence, are they equal?

Answer (score 2):

The python module [Machine Learning Python](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/) (**mlpy**) has an [LCS](http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/lcs.html) method including an LCS for real series:

http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/docs/3.5/lcs.html

Perhaps you could also adapt the LCS algorithm for strings and test your own implementation against mlpy.

A quick google search results in the folloing Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence#Python

I copied the content for backup purpose:

> **Computing the length of the LCS**
>
> ```
> def LCS(X, Y):
> m = len(X)
> n = len(Y)
> # An (m+1) times (n+1) matrix
> C = [[0] * (n + 1) for _ in range(m + 1)]
> for i in range(1, m+1):
>     for j in range(1, n+1):
>         if X[i-1] == Y[j-1]: 
>             C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + 1
>         else:
>             C[i][j] = max(C[i][j-1], C[i-1][j])
> return C
> ```
>
> **Reading out an LCS**
>
> ```
> def backTrack(C, X, Y, i, j):
> if i == 0 or j == 0:
>     return ""
> elif X[i-1] == Y[j-1]:
>     return backTrack(C, X, Y, i-1, j-1) + X[i-1]
> else:
>     if C[i][j-1] > C[i-1][j]:
>         return backTrack(C, X, Y, i, j-1)
>     else:
>         return backTrack(C, X, Y, i-1, j)
> ```
>
> **Reading out all LCSs**
>
> ```
> def backTrackAll(C, X, Y, i, j):
> if i == 0 or j == 0:
>     return set([""])
> elif X[i-1] == Y[j-1]:
>     return set([Z + X[i-1] for Z in backTrackAll(C, X, Y, i-1, j-1)])
> else:
>     R = set()
>     if C[i][j-1] >= C[i-1][j]:
>         R.update(backTrackAll(C, X, Y, i, j-1))
>     if C[i-1][j] >= C[i][j-1]:
>         R.update(backTrackAll(C, X, Y, i-1, j))
>     return R
> ```
>
> **Usage example**
>
> ```
> X = "AATCC"
> Y = "ACACG"
> m = len(X)
> n = len(Y)
> C = LCS(X, Y)
>
> print "Some LCS: '%s'" % backTrack(C, X, Y, m, n)
> print "All LCSs: %s" % backTrackAll(C, X, Y, m, n)
> ```
>
> It prints the following:
>
> ```
> Some LCS: 'AAC'
> All LCSs: set(['ACC', 'AAC'])
> ```